# Static File On Django 3.2 Not Loading

Tags: python-3.x, django, static, backend, django-3.2

**My Problem is quite simple and yet I'm finding it so hard to solve it.**
The problem is I am not able to load the CSS File and image which are on the static folder located on the root folder of the project. The static folder is not under the app name.

My project name is "*ecommerce*" and my app name is "*store*".

This is my file hierarchy for my project.

[image]

This is my settings.py

[image]

I have added my app too.

[image]

Yes, the ***STATICFILES_DIRS*** too.

[image]

Tried the other one too.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
```

]

I used ***temp.html*** for showing the demo and here is my code.

[image]

And the CSS file which is named ***main.css***

[image]

After doing all the things properly, the CSS file and image won't load.

[image]

***Errors That I got in my terminal***

[image]

***And in developer mode in Chrome***

[image]

**As I know this is quite a rookie mistake and I am a beginner. I can't continue forward till this problem is solved. I'd be grateful if someone could come forward and assist me in resolving the issue.**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6562458)

Comment: Please add your url pattern file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all move your static folder in app directory that is *store* here

Now make another store folder inside the static

`static/store`

Now make all folders like css, js and img in static/store directory. Then Replace your css link in this link

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">`

And img tag link.

`<img src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}" alt="My image">`

Comment: However, I wanna try it without moving to the "store" directory.